# Diplaying only the center of an image at a given height and width?

Tags: html, css, image-processing

When medium renders a list of card showing blog posts each card has the header image shown and it's at full width, but the center of it has been cut out.

Medium does this by cutting off the top and the bottom of each image so that they are all the same size like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same with pure CSS.  It has to work for different size images.  For example one image could have a height of 500px and another 1000px and both the same width, and we only want to display the 200px center of each at full width.

End end goal is to render the center of each image consistently within cards.  This is how Medium's cards look:

[image]

I've tried cropping out the top and bottom of each image, however since they are different sizes, the result ends up not having fixed dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the image as a background-image to a div, like so

```
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

You can style the div using the background CSS rules, which allow more over how your image looks, scaling, and positioning.

```
.background-image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:url('../assets/your-image.svg');
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As shown, with this class you can also go on to set `min-height` and other properties as you please, to create card images which are standardised.

Comment: Awesome - I think that's a great start!  Made a little demo of your answer here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clipping-images